# passing variable in regular expression in javascript for string match

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

Suppose i need to use string match in javascript to get a result equivalent to the LIKE operator.

```
WHERE "str1" LIKE '%str2%';
```

The below match expression works.

```
var str1="abcd/pqrst"; 
var str2 =  "pqr";

if(str1.match(/^.*pqr.*/)){ //do something};
```

But i need to pass a variable instead of pqr, something like the below statement.Please help.

```
//Wrong
var re = new RegExp("/^.*"+ str2 + ".*/"); 
if(str1.match(re){ //do something}
```

Comment: @elclanrs: This doesnt work : var re = new RegExp("/^.*"+ str2 + ".*/"); 
if(str1.match(re){ //do something}

Answer (score 7):

Here is a quick jsFiddle for you to try

http://jsfiddle.net/jaschahal/kStTc/

```
var re = new RegExp("^.*"+str2+".*","gi"); 
// second param take flags
```

More details here

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

You can also use contains()/indexOf() functions for these simple checks

Answer (score 4):

First, it may be appropriate to use `RegExp.test`. Second, creating a `RegExp` object you shouldn't use `RegExp` literal characters ('/').

So your code becomes:

```
var str1 = 'abcd/pqrst'
   ,str2 = 'pqr'
   ,re = RegExp('^'+str2+'.*');

if (re.test(str1)) { /* do things */}
```

Third, the `RegExp` (`/^pqr.*/`) will test `false` for `str1`. The equivalent of `WHERE "str1" LIKE '%str2%';` is as simple as `RegExp(str2,'i').test(str1)` (note the `i` modifier (case insensitive test)), or even just `~str.indexOf(str2)` (see @[Jeff Bowmans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1426891/jeff-bowman) answer).

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is to confirm that a string occurs in the middle of a different string, use `str1.indexOf(str2) >= 0`. In other languages this would be equivalent to `str1.contains(str2)`, though Javascript strings lack a *contains* method.

If you do want to put str2 in the middle of the regular expression, be sure to [escape it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript).

Comment: Thank you so much! I simply made things complicated!

Comment: Technically for the given sql query that should be `str.indexOf(str2)>-1`, or `~str.indexOf(str2)`. Afaik `LIKE` also returns something if the term between `%` is at the start/at the end of a string value.

Comment: @Jeff: if(str1.contains(str2) was all i needed. Thank you Jeff.That is removed so i am unable to mark it as an answer

Comment: @user930514 Be aware that there is no "String.contains" method in Javascript, though I updated the original answer to reflect that and mention contains anyway.